# what tricks are there to slice this sentence into my desired format?

Tags: python, slice

How do I slice this

```
'Python is an interesting and useful language for numerical computing!'
```

to get

```
'Pto sa neetn n sfllnug o ueia optn!?
```

in Python?

Comment: Welcome to SO! By what operation are you achieving the result? Every other char? What code have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: x = 'Python is an interesting and useful language for numerical computing!'

Comment: I  can do what is in the code below but not sure how to accomplish the goal above.                                                                                                              x = 'Python is an interesting and useful language for numerical computing!'

x[0:7] ##to get word Python
Out[135]: 'Python '

x[68:] ##to get the exclamation
Out[136]: '!'

Answer (score 0):

List indexing magic (rather no magic)

```
data = 'Python is an interesting and useful language for numerical computing!'
print(data)
print(data[0::2])
```

Comment: Thanks Krishna, how do you interpret this code?

Comment: Slicing takes 3 numbers `Start:End:Step`. When `End` is not specified, it iterates until the end of the list.